Looking for a mecha anime where the mechas are called from space and activated using swords
I'm looking for a mecha anime where the protagonist's family was murdered in order to recruit him as a mecha pilot. The murderer was a man with a silver or gold hand. He leaves scars in the house when he killed the protagonist's family.
In this anime, as far as I can recall, the mechas are summoned using swords, and they come from space to the caller's location. Then they fight.
Does anyone know the name of this anime?

Once you make an account on this site, you can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. If an answer is incorrect, it's an excellent chance to [edit] details into your question, e.g. "I know it isn't Edmonton High because the male lead was dark-skinned and everyone had iPhones."

This could be "Gun Sword" (sometimes written as "GUNxSWORD" o "Gun X Sword"). It originally aired in 2005.
Van, the main character, wields a weapon which (as you may guess from the title) behaves like a mix of a gun and a sword, and can be used to call his mecha; the mecha is sent from a space station in orbit around the planet and returns there when there is no more need for it.
The main villain is know as The Claw, and as the name suggests his right hand is a metallic claw; when the series starts, he has already murdered Van's wife, and the protagonist is looking for him to avenge her.

The series is avaialbe on Crunchyroll.

Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for.

Consider clicking on the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as accepted and signal it contains the info you were looking for.
